Pi Zero (not Zero 2) system on a USB drive - how to setup booting?
I have a Pi Zero W (not Zero 2) and need to move the whole system to a SSD (with a USB/SATA adapter) and switch the boot sequence so that the actual boot is "redirected" to the SSD.
I was looking for answers but none of them describes the process (preparation of the disk and modification of the boot SD card), many mention a hyperlink which, unfortunately, points to a non-existing page and some just mention "look in the documentation" but the docs do not contain any such information.
Is there one place where I could find this?

I believe you need bootcode.bin on a sd card - everything else can live on the SSD ... at least, that's how I did it on the Pi1 and Pi2 - NOTE: you want to make sure the PARTUUID of the sd card and ssd are different

You can NOT boot any Pi model before Pi3 from USB because they lack the hardware support.
It is possible to boot from SD Card but use a root partition on an external storage device. This requires changes to cmdline.txt and modifications to /etc/fstab in the root partition to match the PARTUUID of the storage device.
This is most easily accomplished by copying existing root then editing files on the copy. In fact it is possible to have multiple root partitions provided they use the same kernel.
You can also use a SD Card containing only bootcode.bin but I never tried this.

bootcode.bin variant did not work, but changing /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt on the SD card and modifying /etc/fstab on SSD - did.
